# Why do these two decrypt/encrypt functions work only sometimes?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I use `ECDiffieHellmanCng` for exchange of public keys and then `AES` for encrypting/decrypting.

Sometimes the decryption works, other times I get the following error in decryption method: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
Where is the cause of this?

Here is the code:

```
private void Encryption(byte[] key, byte[] unencryptedMessage,out byte[] encryptedMessage, out byte[] iv) // encryption funkcija
        {
            using (Aes aes = new AesManaged())
            {
                aes.Key = key;
                //aes.GenerateIV();
                iv = aes.IV;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                // Encrypt the message
                using (MemoryStream ciphertext = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ciphertext, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(unencryptedMessage, 0, unencryptedMessage.Length);
                        cs.Close();

                    }
                    encryptedMessage = ciphertext.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

private void Decryption(byte[] encryptedMessage, byte[] iv, out byte[] decryptedMessage)
        {
            using (Aes aes = new AesManaged())
            {
                aes.Key = receiversKey;
                aes.IV = iv;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                // Decrypt the message
                using (MemoryStream decryptedBytes = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(decryptedBytes, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(encryptedMessage, 0, encryptedMessage.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    decryptedMessage = decryptedBytes.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which line throws that error? Have you verified the keys and the IV are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using the same padding mode for both encryption and decryption, the most likely causes of invalid padding error are:

1. Different keys that are used for encryption and decryption.
2. Invalid encrypted message passed to `Decryption()` method. You could mistakenly pass an empty string or non-encrypted data.

If this does not help, please provide the code that calls `Encryption()` and `Decryption()` methods and handles the key used in both cases. It's required because those methods itself looks ok, the most likely problem is in passed arguments.